# How to override the default value of a Jenkins parameterized build?

Tags: json, curl, jenkins, jobs, parameterized

I have a parameterized job "dummy" what invokes an `ANT` script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="dummy" basedir="." default="sayit">
    <target name="sayit">
        <echo message="p_foo: ${p_foo}" level="info" />
    </target>
</project>
```

When I execute the `ANT` from command-line

```
ant -Dp_foo=12345678
```

it displays

```
sayit:
    [echo] p_foo: 12345678
```

The job's configuration defines a **String Parameter** with name **p_foo** and default value **bar** what later is reused in the **Build** section where the `ANT` is invoked:

```
Properties: p_foo=$p_foo
```

When I run the job from dashboard it prompts me for a value for **p_foo** and that value is echoed.

Now I need to achieve the same result with **cURL** and **Jersey REST API**.

In the command-line I call

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/job/dummy/buildWithParameters?delay=0sec \
  --data-urlencode json="{'parameter':[{'name':'p_foo', 'value':'1111'}:]}"
```

The job is executed but the value of **p_foo** remains unchanged (**bar**).

What is wrong this approach? The `REST` solution probably will work when the `cURL` solution will be OK.

The above command-line call works but the following Jersey client doesn't:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter;

import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class RestClient {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RestClient.class.getSimpleName());

    private static final String JOB_URI = "http://%s:%s/job/%s/build";
    private static final String JOB_JSON_PARAM = "{\"parameter\":[{\"name\":\"%s\",\"value\":\"%s\"}]}";

    private String hostname;
    private String port;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public RestClient(String p_hostname, String p_port, String p_username, String p_password) {
        this.hostname = p_hostname;
        this.port = p_port;
        this.username = p_username;
        this.password = p_password;
    }

    public String getHostname() {
        return this.hostname;
    }

    public String getPort() {
        return this.port;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    private URI getBaseURI(String p_url) {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri(p_url).build();
    }

    private WebResource getWebResource(String p_url) {
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(this.username, this.password));
        return client.resource(getBaseURI(p_url));
    }

    public String startJenkinsJob(String p_jobname) {
        String uri = String.format(JOB_URI, this.getHostname(), this.getPort(), p_jobname);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, uri);
        WebResource oWebResource = this.getWebResource(uri);
        String json = String.format(JOB_JSON_PARAM, "p_foo", "1111");
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, json);
        ClientResponse response = oWebResource.accept("application/json")
                .type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, json);
        /*if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
        }*/
        return response.getEntity(String.class);
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            RestClient rc = new RestClient("localhost", "8080", "user", "password");
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, rc.startJenkinsJob("dummy"));
        rc = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `build` endpoint instead of `buildWithParameters` and remove the last colon

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/job/dummy/build\?delay\=0sec \ 
  --data-urlencode json="{'parameter':[{'name':'foo', 'value':'1111'}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The above command-line call works but the following Jersey client doesn't:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter;

import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class RestClient {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RestClient.class.getSimpleName());

    private static final String JOB_URI = "http://%s:%s/job/%s/build";
    private static final String JOB_JSON_PARAM = "{\"parameter\":[{\"name\":\"%s\",\"value\":\"%s\"}]}";

    private String hostname;
    private String port;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public RestClient(String p_hostname, String p_port, String p_username, String p_password) {
        this.hostname = p_hostname;
        this.port = p_port;
        this.username = p_username;
        this.password = p_password;
    }

    public String getHostname() {
        return this.hostname;
    }

    public String getPort() {
        return this.port;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    private URI getBaseURI(String p_url) {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri(p_url).build();
    }

    private WebResource getWebResource(String p_url) {
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(this.username, this.password));
        return client.resource(getBaseURI(p_url));
    }

    public String startJenkinsJob(String p_jobname) {
        String uri = String.format(JOB_URI, this.getHostname(), this.getPort(), p_jobname);
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, uri);
        WebResource oWebResource = this.getWebResource(uri);
        String json = String.format(JOB_JSON_PARAM, "p_foo", "1111");
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, json);
        ClientResponse response = oWebResource.accept("application/json")
                .type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, json);
        /*if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
        }*/
        return response.getEntity(String.class);
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            RestClient rc = new RestClient("localhost", "8080", "user", "password");
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, rc.startJenkinsJob("dummy"));
        rc = null;
    }
}
```